# Getting exc_bad_access error only when mallocguard is enabled

Tags: iphone, malloc, guard

I have an app for iPhone in development which works properly when the Malloc guard is not enabled. However when i try to enable the malloc guard i get the following error after the app is loaded.

```
#0  0x95f65684 in objc_msgSend ()
```

`#1  0x30506515 in NSPopAutoreleasePool ()`

`#2  0x30901697 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()`

`#3  0x32046375 in PurpleEventCallback ()`

`#4  0x30245560 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()`

`#5  0x30244628 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()`

`#6  0x308f930d in -[UIApplication _run] ()`

`#7  0x309021ee in UIApplicationMain ()`
Now my problem is that i am not able to debug the exact location where its getting the error.. have tried malloc_error_break but didnt work out.
Is it that malloc guard enabling auto releases some of the objects based on allocation??

Answer (score 0):

You're releasing some memory that's autoreleased. Without seeing any of your code it's difficult to say what exactly the problem is but it would look something like this:

```
NSString* aVar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", worldVariable];

...

[aVar release];
```

This wouldn't crash at the release statement (as the reference count would be at least one) but *would* crash at some later point in the run loop where the autorelease pool is "drained."

Comment: Thanks for the response. The code is a little huge (about 23 .m files) to fit in here. I shall try out ur suggestion and will see whats wrong.